# Best Practices for Transferring Data Between Hadoop Clusters

Tags: linux, rsync, hadoop

**Situation:**
I need to transfer around 100TB from an old Hadoop Cluster to a new Hadoop cluster.  The two clusters have a direct 1GbE connection from the namenode on each cluster. The datanodes are not connected.

**What I've tried:**

- Distcp: This doesn't work because the old and new datanodes are not connected, it would report connection timed out on each mapreduce job.
- hdfs dfs -cp: This is working pretty well so far, but tends to slow down and eventually stop transferring after a few hours.  It also doesn't support compression or good restartability.

**What I'm interested in:**

- Since my connection between Cluster 1 and Cluster 2 is the bottleneck, I am interested in finding a tool that lets me compress the data on Cluster 1 send it over the wire with very little overhead (netcat maybe?), and uncompress it on Cluster 2.  Rsync would be perfect, but i'm not sure how to use that between two Hadoop Clusters.
- Other recommendations that I'm not familiar with.

**My Question:**

- What tools or scripts can I use to transfer data between Cluster 1 and Cluster 2 efficiently given my limitations listed?